# Objective C ePub framework

Tags: ios, epub

I am looking to implement an eBook reader app. I have found an open source PDF viewer that suited my needs. I now would like to know if there are any open source ePub viewers that I could leverage into the app.

Does anyone know of open source ePub viewers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader

Comment: here i am using this library,but in this library they have implemented only for portrait mode could u help me

Answer (score 1):

To provide a more up-to-date answer for those finding this question six years later, two libraries that allow epub parsing & display on iOS are:

- [Folio Reader](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit) and
- [Readium](https://github.com/readium/r2-testapp-swift) (specifically, the [`Streamer`](https://github.com/readium/r2-streamer-swift) subproject)

Comment: Note that the Readium Mobile iOS project is written in Swift 4.