# Any Framework For epub Reader

Tags: ios, epub, ebook-reader

I want to make a e-book reader application for iOS. can anybody suggest me some good epub format book READER LIBRARIES?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C ePub framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826773/objective-c-epub-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you out for making a good ePub reader. There are many libraries as well which you can easily find out.[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)